# Objective-C unrecognized selector on +initialize with the MagicalRecord CocoaPod

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, magicalrecord, cocoapods

<s>**Note:** See update at the bottom of the question, I've managed to get much further in debugging.</s>

I believe this to be an issue with my project setup, but I'm not sure what to look at because there are no compilation errors.

I have MagicalRecord 2.1 (current stable) included in the project with CocoaPods managing it. I haven't changed any build settings for CocoaPods, it's managing my other dependencies perfectly and I haven't had any issues with it at all so far.

I have added `#import <MagicalRecord/CoreData+MagicalRecord.h>` to my `App-Prefix.pch` file, and Xcode is providing me all the symbol suggestions I would expect with a correct setup. I don't get any compiler errors, so I can only assume that CocoaPods has successfully built MR into a library, and I'm successfully importing this into my code.

The problem comes when I initialise MagicalRecord in my application delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
  [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStack];

  //... other code
}
```

The initialisation is almost the first code to be run, and there is nothing else that has been run which would conflict with this.

This line hangs, nothing after that line is executed. I've managed to track down where the hang happens. Passing a message to `MagicalRecord` is causing the class to have `+initialize` called on it, and that isn't working. More specifically, any method on `self` that is called in the initialize method is causing an `unrecognized selector` exception to be thrown.

There are two strange things about this as far as I can see:

1. Why can't it find the method implementations?
2. Why does that cause it to hang?

I don't know enough about how Objective-C uses the initialize method, is it expected to hang when exceptions are thrown in it?

Here is the stack trace for when the exception occurs:

```
frame #0: 0x00007fff93a2e3c5 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
frame #1: 0x00007fff996dc31a CoreFoundation`+[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
frame #2: 0x00007fff996341ee CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 414
frame #3: 0x00007fff99633fd8 CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
frame #4: 0x000000010004e32c River`+[MagicalRecord initialize] + 92 at MagicalRecord.m:89
frame #5: 0x00007fff93a25236 libobjc.A.dylib`_class_initialize + 310
frame #6: 0x00007fff93a250f3 libobjc.A.dylib`prepareForMethodLookup + 164
frame #7: 0x00007fff93a24eef libobjc.A.dylib`lookUpMethod + 71
frame #8: 0x00007fff93a232fc libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 188
frame #9: 0x0000000100001d36 MyApp`-[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] + 86 at AppDelegate.m:46
```

Any help on this, including tricks I can try to debug it further, are greatly appreciated.

<s>**Update:**</s>

After deleting my Derived Data directory, the program was failing to link to the Pods. I believe that Xcode was failing to build the Pods after I added MagicalRecord, and linking to an older version of it (might be wrong on this, I'm not certain).

This appears to be an Xcode and/or CocoaPods issue. I'm trying to work out how I can get it to build the Pod properly, but I'm not an expert on CocoaPods or Xcode build settings, so I'm not sure how far I'll get.

**Update 2:**

There *was* a problem with Xcode and the project setup, that it was linking with an older Pod library, and that only caused issues after the derived data was deleted. Now I'm back to square 1 with the unrecognized selector issue.

Comment: Looks like an issue with something you're calling or MagicalRecord itself.

Comment: This is what I would have thought, but seeing as no one else has reported the problem I suspect it's an issue with my project setup. But I don't know enough about Objective-C internals to know why it wouldn't be able to find the methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to use the `-all_load` linker flag in the **Other Linker Flags** settings in the settings for the product using the Pod library.

When you link to the pod library, clang strips out the unused symbols unless you do, and since +swizzleShorthandMethods isn't called by your application anywhere, it gets stripped out.

Comment: This is close enough, so marked as the answer. The actual problem was that -all_load and -ObjC weren't being used in the main project itself, not the Pods project.

Comment: Adding `-all_load` flag generates `duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AFImageCache` error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, I never solved this, and it looks like no one has any idea why it wasn't working. I tried to work it out with the developer of Magical Record, but in the end the answer was to not use CocoaPods and add the code manually. I wish I could give a better resolution to this, but I don't have time to spend days debugging this issue, and I don't think I know enough about CocoaPods, the Xcode compilation process, and the Objective-C runtime in order to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I manually added the `MagicalRecord` library and encountered this error. My problem was in .pch file, because the import of `MagicalRecord/CoreData+MagicalRecord.h` was above the define: `#define MR_SHORTHAND`.

**Putting the define above import solved the problem for me.**

Answer (score 0):

In your `Podfile` update MagicalRecord reference as follows:

```
pod 'MagicalRecord/Shorthand', '~> 2.2'
```

It will include `#define MR_SHORTHAND` in your `Pods/Pods-MagicalRecord-prefix.pch` file.